# How to use locally installed latest version of nano (on CentOS 7) by default? (No admin privileges)

Tags: software-installation, nano

I compiled the nano editor (version 5.3) on CentOS 7.
However, `which nano` gives `/usr/bin/nano`.

`nano --version` gives `GNU nano version 2.3.1`.

I have locally installed `~/.local/bin/nano --version`  `GNU nano version 5.3`.

The path `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin` is saved in `~/.bash_profile`

I do not have administrative privileges. How do I make the locally installed `version 5.3` the default `nano` editor? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> The path export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin is saved in ~/.bash_profile

Change it to `PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH`

OR

Add to e.g. `$HOME/.bashrc` :

`alias nano=$HOME/.local/bin/nano`